# Is it possible to import two versions of module with the same name in a project?

Tags: python

My project depends on two projects, say, `project_A` and `project_B`, each depending on a separate version of modified caffe, a python wrapper of a deep learning framework.

The directory will be like:

```
caffe_A/
  python/
    caffe/
      __init__.py
caffe_B/
  python/
    caffe/
      __init__.py
app/
  project_A/
    __init__.py
    a.py  # from caffe import xxx
  project_B/
    __init__.py
    b.py  # from caffe import xxx
```

It doesn't work by modifying sys.path in the `__init__.py` of `project_A` and `project_B` to include `caffe_A/python` and `caffe_B/python` only.

It seems that once `caffe` module is imported in `project_A`, `import` in `project_B` will just use the caffe_A version.

Is there a solution instead of renaming `caffe` in caffe_B and replace all `import` in `project_B`?